# Can I add a variable in current data?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to add a variable to the current data.

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id text NOT NULL,
  lat numeric,
  lng numeric,
  CONSTRAINT test_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And this is my table:

```
id        lat       lat
ABC-123   12.05481   14.5844
```

I want to let lat add 0.46367 and let lng minus 0.6899.How to do this?

```
id        lat       lat
ABC-123   12.51848   13.8945
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE
   test
SET
   lat = lat + 0.46367,
   lng = lng - 0.6899
WHERE
   id = 'ABC-123'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do arithmetic operations in SELECT. Try:

```
SELECT id, lat + 0.46367 AS LAT, lng - 0.6899 AS LNG
FROM test
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3ee7b/2)</kbd>

Comment: Hello!I use postgresql .Your content can run,but cannot save in the table.

Comment: If you want to save, use the operation on the other answer. This was only for the SELECT statement, as i got the idea that you were trying to do it in a SELECT for some reason.